# Using multline or equation based on a boolean flag

Tags: environments, amsmath, programming

I am trying to define a new environment `myeq` which can either be an `equation` or a `multline`.   My use case is that in the preamble, I will define `myeq` to be either replicate the functionaly of `equation` or `multline` and then the actual document will only contain `myeq` environments so that by changing the definition in the preamble, it is possible to get the spacing characteristics either of `mutline` or of `equation`.

In particular, this requires that I have to define `myeq` to simply replicate `multline`, as follows:

```
\newenvironment{myeq}{\begin{multline}}{\end{multline}}
```

However, this produces the following error (see MWE below)

> \begin{multline} on input line 8 ended by \end{myeq}.

The error disappears if I replace the `multline` in the definition of `myeq` by `equation`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newenvironment{myeq}{\begin{multline}}{\end{multline}}

\begin{document}
\begin{myeq}
  t
\end{myeq}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't recommend this but `\newenvironment{myeq}{\multiline}{\endmultiline}`

Comment: I'm not sure what you intend with this: `multline` should never be used with a single line equation; perhaps you mean to use `gather`. It should be `\newenvironment{myeq}{\gather}{\endgather}`. Don't do it.

Comment: Yes, that seems to work, thank you.  But I am still wondering if there is a downside to this, and if it is possible to do something similar to the case of `equation`

Comment: @egreg:  I have some text that needs to be formatted both for a 2-column format as well as a single column format.  This means that some equations have to have line breaks inserted in the 2-column version.  Since the `equation` environment simply ignores the newline (`\\`) commands,  I was wondering if I can use that behavior to keep a single copy of each equation in the main text, and control the 2-column vs 1-column spacing differences by means of a flag in the preamble.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The failure has a technical reason that's hinted at in [`texdoc technote`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/amsmath/technote.pdf), section 6.

I suggest something like

```
\iftrue
  \newenvironment{myeq}{\equation}{\endequation}
\else
  \newenvironment{\myeq}
    {\def\eqbreak{\\}\multline}
    {\endmultline}
\fi
\newcommand{\eqbreak}{}
```

with `\eqbreak` rather than `\\` (that's not really ignored inside `equation`) inside `myeq`.

Change `\iftrue` into `\iffalse` if you want `multline` for two column documents.

```
A possibly better implementation:

\documentclass[
% twocolumn
]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{multiequation}
 {%
  \if@twocolumn
    \def\eqbreak{\\}%
    \expandafter\multline
  \else
    \def\eqbreak{}%
    \expandafter\equation
  \fi
 }
 {%
  \if@twocolumn
    \expandafter\endmultline
  \else
    \expandafter\endequation
  \fi
 }
\makeatother
\begin{document}

Some text before the equation to see what happens
and embed the equation into a real paragraph
which should break nicely into a few lines
\begin{multiequation}
\biggl(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-x^{2}}\,dx\biggr)^{\!2}
\eqbreak
=\biggl(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-x^{2}}\,dx\biggr)
 \biggl(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-y^{2}}\,dy\biggr) 
\eqbreak
=\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}^{2}}e^{-x^{2}-y^{2}}\,dx\,dy
\end{multiequation}
and some text after the equation to see what happens
and embed the equation into a real paragraph
which should break nicely into a few lines

\end{document}
```

### Output with `twocolumn` commented out

[image]

### Output with `twocolumn` active

[image]

---

Other than for this application, `multline` should never be used for single line displays. Maybe `gather`, with

```
\newenvironment{myeq}{\gather}{\endgather}
```

but you risk something like the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

A paragraph that ends with a short line preceding a display,
let's see if we can
\begin{equation}
(a+b)^2=a^2+2ab+b^2
\end{equation}

A paragraph that ends with a short line preceding a display,
let's see if we can
\begin{gather}
(a+b)^2=a^2+2ab+b^2
\end{gather}

A paragraph that ends with a short line preceding a display,
let's see if we can

\end{document}
```

[image]

No doubt the second one is ugly.

Comment: Thanks.  The reason I want to format a 'single line display' as a multline is because such a display does not remain a 'single line display' anymore when I move to a two-column format (since the width of the line decreases).  All I am trying to do is to be able to generate both the single column and two-column versions from the same version of the equation that differs only in the placement of the newline commands.

Comment: +1 for citing `technote`.  the `equation` environment was restored to the original latex behavior (after many complaints) so that it *can* be accessed by commands such as `\beq ... \eeq`, but adapting the multi-line display environments was prohibitively complicated.  however, regarding the desire to switch between one- and two-column pages, would it not be possible to test for the number of columns, and then launch `equation` or `gather` as appropriate ("switching off" a necessary `\\ ` for the one-line case)?

Comment: @Piyush I added a better version according to barbara beeton's comment

Comment: @barbarabeeton Good idea!

Comment: very nice example.  too bad i can't add another +1.

Comment: Thanks you @egreg.  That example is perfect for the application I had in mind.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a LuaLaTeX-based approach, which acts as a pre-processor: *Before* TeX's eyes get going, the Lua function `switch_eq` sweeps over all input lines and replaces any instances of `\begin{myeq}` with either `\begin{equation}` or `\begin{gather}` depending on whether the Boolean variable `Gather` is true or false. Ditto with all instances of `\end{myeq}`.

The code further provides two LaTeX macros, named `\GatherTrue` and `\GatherFalse`, which set the value of the Boolean variable `Gather` to either true or false.

In the following screenshot, note that equations (1) and (3) are spaced tightly, whereas (2) -- the one that's generated by `gather` rather than by `equation` -- is spaced profligately.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for "gather" environment

%% Lua-side code
\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode}
Gather = false -- default value of "Gather" is "false"
function switch_eq ( buff )
  if string.find ( buff , "\\begin{myeq}" ) then
    if Gather == true then
      return ( string.gsub ( buff, "\\begin{myeq}", "\\begin{gather}" ) )
    else
      return ( string.gsub ( buff, "\\begin{myeq}", "\\begin{equation}" ) )
    end
  elseif string.find ( buff , "\\end{myeq}" ) then
    if Gather == true then
      return ( string.gsub ( buff, "\\end{myeq}", "\\end{gather}" ) )
    else
      return ( string.gsub ( buff, "\\end{myeq}", "\\end{equation}" ) )
    end
  end
end
luatexbase.add_to_callback ( "process_input_buffer" , switch_eq , "switch_eq" )
\end{luacode}

%% TeX-side code
\newcommand\GatherTrue{\directlua{Gather = true}}
\newcommand\GatherFalse{\directlua{Gather = false}}

\setlength\textwidth{8cm} % just for this example
\begin{document}
----------------------------

\begin{myeq}
1+1=2
\end{myeq}

----------------------------

\GatherTrue
\begin{myeq}
1+1=2
\end{myeq}

----------------------------

\GatherFalse
\begin{myeq}
1+1=2
\end{myeq}

----------------------------
\end{document}
```